# Having a hard time with 'For' Loops

Tags: python

I am new to Python and learning about 'For' loops. What I am trying to do is use a for loop to go through some letters I set in a variable then print specific letters to make a message.

I have gotten multiple errors with basically everything I do and I am now just looking for an example of how to do it the right way.

```
currentpos = 0
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"
for unenc in enc: 
    while True:
        if unenc == unenckey[currentpos]:
            currentpos = 0
            print(unenc)
            break
        elif unenc == 'q':
            print(' ')
            break
        else:
            if currentpos == 11:
                currentpos = 0
            if currentpos != 11:
                currentpos = currentpos + 1
                continue
```

It just goes on forever and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: What do you expect the program to do once currentpos reaches 11? Right now you just start over from 0. You probably want to break out of the inner loop also.

Comment: Just a word of advice: Try to have meaningful variable names and if they are multiple words, separate them using `_`. Although `currentpos` isn't the worst, unenckey or enc are weird imo. Would help you when debugging / reading through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop got stuck on characters which are not found because you never used a `break` on reaching currentpos ==11. You had most of the logic figured out spot on. Just fixing that ends up with the following:

```
currentpos = 0
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"
for unenc in enc: 
    while True:
        if unenc == unenckey[currentpos]:
            currentpos = 0
            print(unenc)
            break
        elif unenc == 'q':
            print(' ')
            break
        else:
            if currentpos == 11:
                currentpos = 0
                break #modified
            if currentpos != 11:
                currentpos = currentpos + 1
                continue
```

I'm afraid the "mamfia" doesn't quite work that way though. Alas. :)

As you get more comfortable with the basic structure, you can use some of the power of python in the `in` operator to check if each letter exists in the unenckey directly.

```
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"
for unenc in enc:
    if unenc == 'q':
        print(' ')
    elif unenc in unenckey:
        print(unenc)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the `while` loop. You've put `while True`, so that's what causes it to go on forever. Change it to this:

```
currentpos = 0
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"
for unenc in enc:
    if unenc == unenckey[currentpos]:
        currentpos = 0
        print(unenc)
        break
    elif unenc == 'q':
        print(' ')
        break
    else:
        if currentpos == 11:
            currentpos = 0
        if currentpos != 11:
            currentpos = currentpos + 1
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
currentpos = 0
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"

for char in enc:
    if char in unenckey:
        print(char)
```

Comment: I understand that you are trying to print the chars of enc that appears also on unenckey, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ensure that your `while loop` always `break`s by updating your code as follow?

```
currentpos = 0
unenckey = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']
enc = "ztxhcccczxbatnnsqhlllowqtdhdzxveqmvbanmfxzibbaqwojrdkls"
for unenc in enc: 
    #print(unenc)
    while True:
        if unenc == unenckey[currentpos]:
            currentpos = 0
            print(unenc)
            break
        elif unenc == 'q':
            print(' ')
            break
        else:
            if currentpos == 11:
                currentpos = 0
            if currentpos != 11:
                currentpos = currentpos + 1
                break #Make sure your while loop breaks!
```

The truth of the matter is  **there is actually no need for the while loop`**  if we will always end it with a  **break**. I am just leaving it there because you have indicated that this is for educational purpose.